# "bad packet length" error after updating to OpenSSL 0.9.8.zf

Tags: c, openssl

I was using OpenSSL version 0.9.8h in an Android project. I update it to the 0.9.8.zf version but now it doesn't work.

The two functions that highlight the problem are **`initialize_client_ctx`** and **`initialize_client_ctx`**. When I call **`SSL_connect`** I get an **`SSL_ERROR_SSL`** error value. By checking details I retrieve a "bad packet length" error (`error:14092073:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_HELLO:bad packet length`).

The point in the code is indicated in a comment. The code works well with the previous version. I attach also a Wireshark capture file. Any ideas?

[image]

```
SSL_CTX *initialize_client_ctx(const char *keyfile, const char *certfile,
                           const char *password, int transport)
{
SSL_METHOD *meth = NULL;
X509 *cert = NULL;
SSL_CTX *ctx;

if (transport == IPPROTO_UDP) {
    meth = DTLSv1_client_method();
} else if (transport == IPPROTO_TCP) {
    meth = TLSv1_client_method();
} else {
    return NULL;
}

ctx = SSL_CTX_new(meth);

if (ctx == NULL) {
    //print ... Couldn't create SSL_CTX
    return NULL;
}

if (password[0] != '\0') {
    SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata(ctx, (void *) password);
    SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb(ctx, password_cb);
}

if (tls_client_local_cn_name[0] != '\0') {
    cert = _tls_set_certificate(ctx, tls_client_local_cn_name);
}

if (cert==NULL && certfile[0] != '\0') {
    //print several warnings....
}

if (cert!=NULL)
{
    X509_free(cert);
    cert = NULL;
}



/* Load the CAs we trust */
{
    char *caFile = 0, *caFolder = 0;
    int fd = open(eXosip_tls_ctx_params.root_ca_cert, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd >= 0) {
        struct stat fileStat;
        if (fstat(fd, &fileStat) < 0) {
        } else {
            if (S_ISDIR(fileStat.st_mode)) {
                caFolder = eXosip_tls_ctx_params.root_ca_cert;
            } else {
                caFile = eXosip_tls_ctx_params.root_ca_cert;
            }
        }
        close(fd);
    }

    {
        int verify_mode = SSL_VERIFY_PEER;

        SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, verify_mode, &verify_cb);
        SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ctx, ex_verify_depth + 1);
    }
}

SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_ALL | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 |
                    SSL_OP_NO_SESSION_RESUMPTION_ON_RENEGOTIATION |
                    SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE);

if(!SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx,"ALL")) {
    //print ...  set_cipher_list: cannot set anonymous DH cipher
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    return NULL;
}

return ctx;
}



static int _tls_tl_ssl_connect_socket(struct socket_tab *sockinfo)
{
X509 *cert;
BIO *sbio;
int res;

if (sockinfo->ssl_ctx == NULL) {
    sockinfo->ssl_ctx =
        initialize_client_ctx(eXosip_tls_ctx_params.client.priv_key,
                              eXosip_tls_ctx_params.client.cert,
                              eXosip_tls_ctx_params.client.priv_key_pw,
                              IPPROTO_TCP);

    sockinfo->ssl_conn = SSL_new(sockinfo->ssl_ctx);
    if (sockinfo->ssl_conn == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    sbio = BIO_new_socket(sockinfo->socket, BIO_NOCLOSE);

    if (sbio == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    SSL_set_bio(sockinfo->ssl_conn, sbio, sbio);

}

do {
    struct timeval tv;
    int fd;
    fd_set readfds;

    res = SSL_connect(sockinfo->ssl_conn);

    res = SSL_get_error(sockinfo->ssl_conn, res);
    if (res == SSL_ERROR_NONE) {
        //printf... SSL_connect succeeded
        break;
    }

    if (res != SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ && res != SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE) {

        //<-- here there is a problem res == SSL_ERROR_SSL

        //print ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()));
        //print ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));

        return -1;
    }

    tv.tv_sec = SOCKET_TIMEOUT / 1000;
    tv.tv_usec = (SOCKET_TIMEOUT % 1000) * 1000;
    //retry the connection
    fd = SSL_get_fd(sockinfo->ssl_conn);
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(fd, &readfds);
    res = select(fd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    if (res < 0) {
        //print error
        return -1;
    } else if (res > 0) {
        //print...connetrion done! 
    } else {
        //socket timeout, no data to read
        return 1;
    }
} while (!SSL_is_init_finished(sockinfo->ssl_conn));

if (SSL_is_init_finished(sockinfo->ssl_conn)) {
    //print.. SSL_is_init_finished done
} else {
    //print.. failed
}

cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(sockinfo->ssl_conn);
if (cert != 0) {
    int cert_err;
    tls_dump_cert_info("tls_connect: remote certificate: ", cert);
    cert_err = SSL_get_verify_result(sockinfo->ssl_conn);
    if (cert_err != X509_V_OK) {
        //print... Failed to verify remote certificate
        tls_dump_verification_failure(cert_err);
        if (eXosip_tls_ctx_params.server.cert[0] != '\0') {
            X509_free(cert);
            return -1;
        } else if (cert_err != X509_V_ERR_DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT
                   && cert_err != X509_V_ERR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
                   && cert_err != X509_V_ERR_CRL_HAS_EXPIRED
                   && cert_err != X509_V_ERR_CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
                   && cert_err != X509_V_ERR_CERT_REVOKED
                   && cert_err != X509_V_ERR_CERT_UNTRUSTED
                   && cert_err != X509_V_ERR_CERT_REJECTED) {
            X509_free(cert);
            return -1;
        }

    }

    X509_free(cert);
} else {
    //print .. No certificate received
    /* X509_free is not necessary because no cert-object was created -> cert == NULL */
    if (eXosip_tls_ctx_params.server.cert[0] == '\0') {
 #ifdef ENABLE_ADH
        /* how can we guess a user want ADH... specific APIs.. */
        sockinfo->ssl_state = 3;
        return 0;
 #endif
    }

    return -1;
}

sockinfo->ssl_state = 3;
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Maybe you could try it with the latest  Openssl lib, such as [openssl-1.0.2c ](https://www.openssl.org/source/)? Since it worked in the older version, I guess it might be a issue/bug brought in 0.9.8.zf

Comment: I can try, but the current working version is quite old, I suppose there are several changes in new versions that cause my code not working well

Comment: I saw some discussion about this issue/bug, please refer to [is OpenSSL compiled with no-tlsext?](https://www.apachehaus.com/forum/index.php?topic=111.0) and [This appears to be related to the addition of TLS 1.1 and 1.2 support to the version of OpenSSL](http://askubuntu.com/questions/116020/python-https-requests-urllib2-to-some-sites-fail-on-ubuntu-12-04-without-proxy)

Comment: So my suggestion is to try a few openssl libs to verification firstly rather than to debug/change your code.

Comment: @Selvaline If the problem got solved, then write an answer to your question and accept it. That would be so much cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED** Thanks to Eric Tsui that helps me to figure out the problem. The 'hello' that I receive from the server in the handshake has zero length. To solve this I modified the file openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c in the following way (toggling off the length control):

```
diff -ur ./s3_clnt.c ./original/s3_clnt.c
--- submodules/externals/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c  2015-06-29 14:59:56.723462992 +0200
+++ ../../opensslOrig/s3_clnt.c 2015-06-29 15:00:22.487464221 +0200
@@ -868,12 +868,14 @@
 }
#endif

+#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_TLSEXT
 if (p != (d + n)) {
     /* wrong packet length */
     al = SSL_AD_DECODE_ERROR;
     SSLerr(SSL_F_SSL3_GET_SERVER_HELLO, SSL_R_BAD_PACKET_LENGTH);
     goto f_err;
 }
+#endif

 return (1);
f_err:
```

Comment: Good job on tracking down the problem. But OpenSSL 0.9.8 is ***really*** anemic. It lacks most Elliptic Curve gear; it lack s TLS 1.1 and 1.2; and it lacks the AEAD cipher suites. You should upgrade to OpenSSL 1.0.2.